# generating a new object version-id in s3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a bucket with objects that is unversioned. Then I turned on versioning and those existing objects do not have a versionId, only newly uploaded objects will. What I would like is to be able to generate a versionId for each of the objects that currently do not have one, and without have to resort to workarounds like copy to a temporary location and then override the original object. That is costly in terms of extra, versioned, storage that will incur, and also just time consuming to copy that much data. Is there a way to generate a version-id in place?

This is the error:

`An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes.`

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you trying to overcome a particular problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I turned on versioning and those existing objects do not have a versionId, only newly uploaded objects will.

That's not correct.  When you enable versioning on an unversioned bucket, all of the existing objects have their version-id set to the 4-byte string `null`.  This is not "null" as in "empty" or "non-existent" but an actual string.

This value behaves the same as any other version-id, from your perspective, since version-ids have no meaning (they're opaque strings, not numbers, as shown in some of the documented examples).

Answer (score 0):

As the error it returns is very helpful, just do what it suggests and change any of the things that will make the object have a different version than before. For me the easiest was to just add a user metadata.